# Iptables overridden after reboot in Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kvm-virtualization, reset

On my Ubuntu server (installed KVM and Kimchi), I noticed that the `iptables` are changed after a reboot. Unfortunately I did not find out which script is responsible for these changes.

I tried to store my own settings in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4? and bring them back after reboots by adding

```
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

to `/etc/rc.local`. When I manually execute this line, it works properly. But when I rebooted the machine again, my settings were overridden by the other script again. I conclude that my line from `/etc/rc.local`is executed before this external script, hence overridden.

Which one could it be and how could I find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), Ubuntu's own firewall control software.

Comment: No, it says that it is disabled?